# Is there an easier way for making a List in a HashMap inside another HashMap?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, hashmap, keyvaluepair

I'm working on a program that authorizes a user of a server to access it with a generated key, and I'm currently working on the generation part. The owner of the server can specify how many keys, the server ID, and the duration of the keys. I need to store and check if the key matches the serverID so users can use the keys to gain access.

The only thing I could think of was a complicated HashMap combination with another HashMap inside, with an List inside of that HashMap. The first String is the server ID which is unique to each server, the List is for the batch of generated keys, and the final String value is for the duration of those keys.

```
static HashMap<List<String>, String> keyTimeBundle = new HashMap<>();
static List<String> generatedKeys = new ArrayList<>();
static HashMap<String, HashMap<List<String>, String>> clientGeneratedKeys = new HashMap<>();
```

The problem is that I don't have any idea where to start when checking if the key goes with the matching server ID because the key is in another HashMap inside a List. I'm sure there's another easier way to implement this but I haven't thought of it yet so feel free to not use my method to explain how to store and check the values.

Comment: The answer is to write your own objects rather than build these (somewhat ridiculous) data structures.

Comment: You are trying to create a complex structure with lists and maps. The best solution in my opinion would be create objects to represent the data you need. Create an object Server to store the servers with a list of Keys inside. The object Key can have the generated key and the duration. This will make your code much more simple to understand.

Comment: Although it could/should be slightly simplified to `Map<String, Map<List<String>, String>>`, you should definitely define an appropriate `interface` with the methods that you need. Note that using a `List<String>` as the **key** for a map looks particularly dubious. I can hardly imagine a sensible way of doing lookups there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple different approach would be use `HashMap<String,String>` only.
You can take key as
 `<serverId><delimiter(such as '#')><generatedKey>` and value as the duration of that key in that particular server.

While searching you just concatenate serverId and key and just check the duration.

Answer (score 3):

It's definitely getting unwieldy. It's time to pare back the overgrowth with some carefully thought out classes. Giving good names to the concepts in your programs makes it a lot easier to reason through the logic and data structures you need.

```
class Id {
    String value;
}

class Server {
    Id id;
    List<Key> keys;
}

class Key {
    Id id;
    Server server;
    Instant expirationDate;
}
```

Each key has a reference to the server it's for, and each server has a list of keys that give access to it. Rather than assigning expiration times to bundles of keys, give each key its own expiration time. Creating a batch of keys just means creating a bunch of keys and giving them all the same expiration time.

The `Id` class might just be a simple wrapper around `String`, but it makes the code a bit easier to read since you don't have to figure out what different `String`s are (are they IDs? names?). The name `Id` makes it clear that they're ID strings.

Once you have your classes it makes it easier to think about what additional data structures you'll need. For instance, you'll want some sort of global map to look up servers by ID.

```
public static Map<Id, Server> serversById;
```

Comment: That `Id` class is going a step too far, IMHO. But you should **definitely** say some words about `equals` and `hashCode` when suggesting a solution like this. Otherwise, one can foresee the trouble that the asker will run into.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you implement a POJO representation of a key

```
public class Key{
    private String key;
    //duration is key specific this gives you more flexibility in issuing temporary individual keys
    private long duration;
    ....
```

then you store each server keys list in a map

```
HashMap<String, List<Key>> clientGeneratedKeys = ...
```

As for checking, you check whether that server's keys list contains the submitted key (don't forget to implement the Key class  equals based on comparing the 'key' attribute)

```
clientGeneratedKeys.get("Server Id").contains("submitted key");
```

you will need some null-safety checks in the previous line of code